# C# Assembly loaded in one class, throws an exception in another

Tags: c#, reflection, dependencies, loading, .net-assembly

I have a very weird situation here:

```
internal class Loader {
    internal void Load() {
        UseAssembly();
    }
    
    private void UseAssembly() {
        var marshaller = new Marshaller();
        Assembly assembly = marshaller.LoadAssembly();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Marshaller {
    internal Assembly LoadAssembly() {
        return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("C:\\Users\\OLNO\\Downloads\\SkinProject1.dll");
    }
}
```

Now here is the interesting part:

[image]

It is interesting, because the file exists in that location, and because the exception itself is thrown at this line:

```
Assembly assembly = marshaller.LoadAssembly();
```

but not this one:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("C:\\Users\\OLNO\\Downloads\\SkinProject1.dll"
```

and when instead of code above I have this one, it works just fine:

```
internal class Loader {
    internal void Load() {
        UseAssembly();
    }
    
    private void UseAssembly() {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("C:\\Users\\OLNO\\Downloads\\SkinProject1.dll");
    }
}
```

I'm working in Visual Studio 2019, and I've tried cleaning the build and rebuilding the solution. This issue looks pretty much like magic to me... How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The location of the exception might be bogus, as binding errors often manifest in strange ways. Either that assembly, or your own assembly, references `SkinProject1` with that exact version, and it cannot be found.

Comment: @Charlieface sorry for taken time, I figured my issue. It was due to an `AppDomain`. I messed some things up, and now I can't access members of `Marshaller` because of that. Thanks for a try anyways :)

Comment: using FUSLOGVW.exe could help finding the source of the problem